# Google app engine redirect everything to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-app-engine, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect everything to index.php

the old script on shared hosting has followng htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

and yes Im too noob to work out how to do this in google app engine(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below to your app.yaml , this should do the trick :)

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Error: Not Found

The requested URL /test was not found on this server.

Comment: can you post your full app.yaml aand the full url that gives the error